# How to use Nuxt 3 server as a passthrough API with FormData to hide external endpoints

Tags: api, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to get my head around the Nuxt /server API and can't seem to figure out how to send a POST request with form-data (ie files) to Nuxt server to forward on to an external service:

In my `pages.vue` file I have this method:

```
async function onSubmit() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  for (let file of form.files) {
    await formData.append("image", file);
  }

  await $fetch("/api/send", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData
  });
}
```

and then in `/server/api/send.js` I have:

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const { method } = event.node.req;

// I THINK THE ISSUE IS HERE 
  const body =
    method !== "GET" && method !== "HEAD"
      ? await readMultipartFormData(event)
      : undefined;

  const response = await $fetch.raw(https://*******, {
      method,
      baseURL: *********,
      headers: {
      },
      body: body
    });

   return response._data;
}
```

I'm effectively creating a passthrough API using Nuxt so that the external endpoint isn't exposed to the end user. Just can't figure out how to access the formData in the correct format to pass through on the server side. I don't think I am supposed to use `readMultipartFormData()` because that seems to be parsing the data somehow whereas I just want to pass the formData straight through to the external API. Any tips?

I've tried using both `readMultipartFormData()` and `readBody()` and neither seem to work. I don't actually need to read the body but rather get it and pass it through without any formatting...

Comment: Can you log the output of `readMultipartFormData`? Is it an object?

Comment: The output of `readMultipartFormData` is an array of objects:


```
  [                                                                             
  {
    name: 'image',
    filename: 'ticket.png',
    type: 'image/png',
    data: <Buffer 89 50 4e 47 52 00 00 01 20 00 00 ae ce 1c e9 00 00 00 84 ... 42504 more bytes>
  },
  {
    name: 'image',
    filename: 'shortform.svg',
    type: 'image/svg+xml',
    data: <Buffer 3c 73 76 67 74 74 70 3a 2f 72 67 2f 32 30 35 77 42 6f 78 3d 22 30 ... 4871 more bytes>
  },
  { name: 'comment', data: <Buffer > }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled a lot with this issue, there are no clean ways, and every time i have to deal with file upload with Nuxt 3, i just use nuxt-proxy frontside to bypass the server, that's ugly too...

```
  proxy: {
    options: {
      target: 'https://my-backend.herokuapp.com',
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api/mediaupload/': '/api/mediaupload/',
      },
      pathFilter: [
        '/api/mediaupload/',
      ]
    }
  },
```

and in my page :

```
    const addFiles = (e: { target: { files: any; }; }): void => {
      console.log('e',e)
      const formData = new FormData();
      for (let i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
        formData.append("file"+i, e.target.files[i]);
      }
      formData.append("foo", bar);
      refInput = formData
    };
```

submit button :

```
const submitFiles = async () => {
  domError.value = null
  const token = useStatefulCookie('token')
  if (token.value && refInput) {
    const authorization = `Bearer ${token.value.access_token}`
    const data = await $fetch("/api/mediaupload/", {
      method: "POST",
      body: refInput,
      headers: {
        // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', <- finally useless
        'Authorization': authorization,
      },
      async onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
        domError.value = response._data
      }
    })
  }
  else return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the data with formdata to the endpoint try this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-to-formdata

code:

```
import { serialize } from 'object-to-formdata';
const formData = serialize(body);
const response = await $fetch.raw(https://*******, {
      method,
      baseURL: *********,
      headers: {
      },
      body: formData
    });
```

Comment: your method is not working because i have teh same trouble @aonghas did you manage to made it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work with ugly solution, first you have to update nuxt to version 3.2.0 min then here my front side

```
let jobApplicationDTO = {
            firstName: values.firstName,
            lastName: values.lastName,
            email: values.email,
            phoneNumber: values.phoneNumber,
            company: values.company,
            shortDescription: values.shortDescription
        };

        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("application", new Blob([JSON.stringify(jobApplicationDTO)], {type: "application/json"}));
        formData.append("file", values.file) ;

        //formData.append("file", values.file );
        await useFetch("/api/application", {
            method: "POST",
            body: formData,
            onResponse({request, response, options}) {
                // Process the response data
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    errorMessage.value = "";
                    successMessage.value = "Your application wa sent successfully, you will be contacted soon !";
                }
            },
            onResponseError({request, response, options}) {
                console.debug(response);
                if (response.status === 400) {
                    successMessage.value = "";
                    errorMessage.value = "There may be an issue with our server. Please try again later, or send an email to support@mantiq.com";
                } else {
                    successMessage.value = "";
                    errorMessage.value = "Sorry we couldn’t send the message, there may be an issue with our server. Please try again later, or send an email to support@mantiq.com";
                }
            },
        });
    }
```

and server side

```
import {FormData} from "node-fetch-native";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const {BACKEND_REST_API, ENQUIRY_TOKEN} = useRuntimeConfig();       
//retrieve frontend post formData
const form = await readMultipartFormData(event);
    const applicationUrl = BACKEND_REST_API + '/job/apply'
    console.log("url used for enquiry rest call :" + applicationUrl);
    console.log("Job application token :" + ENQUIRY_TOKEN);
    
    const formData = new FormData();

    console.log(form);


    if (form) {
        formData.append(form[0].name, new Blob([JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(form[0].data))], {type:  form[0].type}));
        formData.append(form[1].name, new Blob([form[1].data], {type: form[1].type}), form[1].filename);
    }

    console.log(formData.values);

    return await $fetch(applicationUrl, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            Authorization: ENQUIRY_TOKEN,
        },
    });
})
```

What is funny is on frontend you have to create a formData , then to get content and to recreate a formData from your previous formData converted in MultiFormPart[], i created a ticket on nuxt to see how to do it properly