# How to send form data in POST request in Nuxt 3 to django DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am trying to use Nuxt 3 as a server to pass through API requests. I would like to make FormData requests to a Django DRF API through my Nuxt server to POST data and images.

basically, the usecase is filling a simple form with data and images and send the formdata to a django backend. Here are more details.

In `pages.vue`:

```
const taskData = reactive({
  title: '',
  city: '',
  description: '',
  category: route.params.cat_slug,
  subCat: '',
  image_1: [],
  image_2: [],
  image_3: []
})

const submitTaskForm = async () => {
  let formData = new FormData()

  formData.append('title', taskData.title)
  formData.append('city', taskData.city)
  formData.append('description', taskData.description)
  formData.append('category', taskData.category)
  formData.append('subCat', taskData.subCat)
  taskData.image_1.forEach((fileItem) => {
    formData.append('image_1', fileItem.file)
  })
  taskData.image_2.forEach((fileItem) => {
    formData.append('image_2', fileItem.file)
  })
  taskData.image_3.forEach((fileItem) => {
    formData.append('image_3', fileItem.file)
  })

  const data = await useFetch('/api/tasks/add/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })

  return data
}
```

in `/server/api/add.post.ts`

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const body = await readBody(event)
    const access = getCookie(event, 'access') || null

    try {
        const data = await $fetch(process.env.API_BASE_URL + "/api/tasks/add/", {
            method: "POST",
            body: body,
            headers: {
                Authorization: "Bearer " + access,
            },
        })
        return data

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error
    }
})
```

now the backend part with the view handling the form:

```
class TasksCreate(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = TasksSerializer
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]

    def post(self, request):
        data = self.request.data

        title = data['title']
        city = data['city']
        description = data['description']
        category_slug = data['category']
        subCat = data['subCat']
        image_1 = request.FILES.get('image_1', "")
        image_2 = request.FILES.get('image_2', "")
        image_3 = request.FILES.get('image_3', "")

        try:
            if not Subcategories.objects.filter(slug=subCat, category__slug=category_slug).exists():
                return Response(
                    {'error': 'The subcategory does not correspond to the category.', },
                    status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )

            task = Task.objects.create(
                title=title,
                city=city,
                description=description,
                slug='%s-%s' % (slugify(title), randint(1000, 10000)),
                category=get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug),
                sub_category = get_object_or_404(Subcategories, slug=subCat),
                created_by=request.user,
                image_1=image_1,
                image_2=image_2,
                image_3=image_3,
            )

            task.save()

            return Response(
                {'task': 'Task created successfully', },
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return Response(
                {'error': 'Something went wrong when creating the task'},
                status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
            )
```

the error: `Unsupported Media Type: /api/tasks/add/`

I have tried with `readBody` `readRawBody` `readMultipartFormData` and also adding `"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"` to headers.

Also, hitting directly the view with Postman work perfectly so my guess it's nuxt 3 not sending correctly the form.

Comment: I sent a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349702/how-to-use-nuxt-3-server-as-a-passthrough-api-with-formdata-to-hide-external-end

Comment: your proposed solution doesn't seem to work either for my case. I cannot relate if the problem comes from Nuxt or Django... 
I tried to simplify the code in `/server/api/add.post.ts`

```
...
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('title', 'test')
...
```
And I got this error: `django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: 'title'`

Comment: This leads me to think that the problem comes from Nuxt as the body seems to be empty in django side:
The body: `<QueryDict: {}>`
The headers: `{'Content-Length': '', 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----formdata-undici-0.9045171305078061', 'Host': '127.0.0.1:8000', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGc...', 'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Language': '*', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'User-Agent': 'undici', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}`

Comment: i think you have to add the header content type in your backend query from nuxt to django, and in django to add the consume, for my side i put a json object and file , on backend i had to add this @Consumes( MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA )
 public Response apply(@Context HttpHeaders httpheaders, @FormDataParam( "file" ) InputStream file, @FormDataParam( "file" ) FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail, @FormDataParam( "application" ) JobApplicationDTO dto) {, it means here Django does not understand what you send to it

Comment: @Minseven Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same issue at the moment and spent hours already going through various refactoring, trying out 3rd party libraries like formidable but still can't get it to work. In Postman it works flawlessly.

Comment: @Cos not really, I have an ugly solution

I first get the cookie;
```const { data: cookie } = await useFetch('/api/getCookie')```

then use it along side with my formdata:

```const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', taskData.title)
    formData.append('city', taskData.city)
    // and the rest with images

  const { data: addTask, error: addTaskError } = await useFetch(config.public.drf_baseURL + '/api/tasks/add/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + cookie.value.cookies.access,
    }
  })```